# Statistics: Odds Textbook Question

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

By Fair Odds Rule, chance odds against should equal to payoff odds against.

This means

[image]

Then how do I use that to derive the house percentage (the amount the house takes as fee when payout is lower) that's given in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your approach says that $r_{pay} = r_{fair},$ which is only true if the odds offered are fair (i.e. the house percentage is zero). The fair odds is defined so that the true probability of the better winning is $$\frac{1}{1+r_{fair}}. $$ On average, the house collects $$ \frac{r_{fair}}{1+r_{fair}}\times 1$$ and pays out $$\frac{1}{1+r_{fair}}\times r_{pay}$$ so their house percentage is the difference of these two.

Comment: So $r_{pay}$ in your 3rd equation is not the same as $r_{pay}$ in the definition at the beginning which is equal to $r_{fair}$?

Comment: @A_for_Abacus What definition at the beginning? $r_{pay}$ is whatever the actual odds offered are. Like if the bet pays $5$ to $1,$ $r_{pay}$ is $5.$

Comment: Wow, I had re-read this answer so many times to get how you came up with those equations, but okay. 

It's missing a lot of explainations for example, equation 2 is actually the probability that the house wins multiply by the amount of the stake (1). The 3rd equation is the probability that the player wins multiplied by the amount paid.